# Can sparksql or hiveserver2 connect to 2 different metastores simultaneously?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cassandra, hive, datastax

Use case is:

- Datastax DSE Cluster running Cassandra, HiveMetastore(Cassandra based) and SparkSQL holds the DDL of External tables pointing to DSEFS
- EC2 Cluster running HiveMetastore(MySQL based), HiveServer2 and SparkSQL. This metastore holds the DDL of External tables pointing to S3

Is it possible to have a single SparkSQL connection that can read data from both metastores (ie the DSEFS tables from HMS(Cassandra) and the S3 tables from HMS(MySQL))? From what I've seen a single HMS does not handle both S3 and DSEFS external tables.

Comment: Maybe try https://github.com/HotelsDotCom/waggle-dance/blob/master/README.md